# Can be fetch method compiled to the older version of JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

**Can be fetch method transpire to the older version of JS?**

E.g in React app, can babel compiled to the older version of JS, and on that way get better support in browsers.

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not supported in IE on any version, in React, can Babel compile fetch to any other method? XMLHttpRequest and basic ajax in JS? Or, is required to use axios on example?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/625/top-5-best-javascript-polyfills-for-the-fetch-api